Cierre de sesión en Zoho Catalyst
Estoy intentando crear una página web para alojarla en Zoho Catalyst. Al intentar crear un cierre de sesión, siguiendo la documentación, recibo el siguiente error:
ReferenceError: Catalyst is not defined en logout.html
El código que tengo es el siguiente:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cierre de Sesión</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a class="boton" id="cerrar-sesion" href="#">Cerrar Sesión</a></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <script src="https://static.zohocdn.com/catalyst/sdk/js/4.0.0/catalystWebSDK.js"></script>
    <script>
        var catalyst = new Catalyst({
            projectID: 'project_ID',
            clientID: 'Client_ID',
            clientSecret: 'Client_Secret'
        });

        catalyst.init();

        function cerrarSesion(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var redirectURL = "https://redirect-url.com/baas/logout?logout=true&PROJECT_ID=my_project_ID";
";
            catalyst.auth.signOut(redirectURL)
            .then(function() {
                console.log("Sesión cerrada correctamente");
                window.location.href = redirectURL;
            })
            .catch(function(error) {
                console.error("Error al cerrar sesión:", error);
            });
        }

        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.getElementById("cerrar-sesion").addEventListener("click", cerrarSesion);
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>



¿Alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?
He incluso intentado con IA para corregir el error, pero sigue igual cada que ejecuto el código.
